# Simple installer for Qt C++ project, targeting Windows only

Tags: c++, qt, installation, qt-creator

For a small C++ / Qt project I'd like to create an installer.

1. Code written in Qt Creator
2. Basically (when some Qt dlls have been added), a simple xcopy install is possible
3. I could just pack (zip/rar) the files, but I want to "have a little installer feeling"
4. There are no registry entries, etc.
5. Code is for Win Desktop only, so no cross platform requirements

Basically the installer shall

1. Ask for target dir
2. Ask for license acceptance
3. .. and install

From my perspective (as programmer) the installer should be **easy to setup and learn**. I'd be ideal if I could create it from within Qt Creator. Since it is for a non-commercial open source project the installer software **has to be free** (or at least very reasonable priced).

What would you recommend?

Comment: There's [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It's scriptable, so you can add it as a step to your makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this one long time ago
http://www.clickteam.com/website/world/install-creator

But now I use install shield but it has a lot of features you do not seem to need them and it's license is about $2k

Comment: I would also be interested in actually CREATING the "installer" for my project. It probably is possible, I just never thought about it :)

Comment: Fine for my scenario, took me about 10 mins to get a installer version running. Thanks for the hint. The other installer creator seems even a little more sophisticated, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12346575/356726 , but for the time I stick with this one here.

Answer (score 4):

For what you need the [free edition of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) is enough. It does not require any scripting, just drag and drop your files, than specify the default installation folder and dialogs that you need. The free edition is only for ["Simple" projects](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), which is more than enough for you. It also includes a [command line interface](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/command-line.html), if you need one to automate your builds.

Comment: Also an excellent hint, have tried the other installer first and it does what I need. But your help is very much appreciated. Maybe I'll switch any time later.